# AWS Instance Password lost after Login

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, password, putty, aws-cli

As the title suggested I have lost my Linux Instance password. I have already accessed it via putty and it's ppk key. But I don't remember the password of system.

Is there any another way to access the system again?

[image: Password Forget]

Answer (score 7):

Your screenshot says "server refused our key". That means you don't have the private key for your instance. I'm not sure there is a password.

You can try [something like this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/) to mount the volume then reset the password / create a new key.

Comment: And the screenshot clearly shows that the login attempt is done as `root`. As long as root login with password was not enabled on purpose this will not work.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no passwords set by default. Important is that you try to login with the correct user.

Depending on which AMI you selected this can vary. `ec2-user` for AWS Linux, `ubuntu` for Ubuntu, `centos` for CentOS.

Comment: Actually, it's Linux Instance, and I forget the password as it was set by another person, and I want to recover the password now.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that you cannot get access to system. You can create AMI of your instance, create a volume of that AMI and then create a new instance and mount that volume on new instance and recover the data.

Comment: p.s. use ubuntu as default user with key.